# DIY headphone preamp

Tags: audio, diy

I would like to make an amplifier with following specs:

- input from TV RCA jack
- output 1-2 3.5mm jacks
- powered by USB
- volume control (if possible make it somehow wireless)

As i am new to electrical engineering i'm looking for some tips on where to start and if it possible at all?

Comment: Start with Google? There are only about [a million headphone preamp designs out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=headphone+preamp+schematic&client=firefox-a&hs=5rJ&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=JsPfUovdO6HmsATmg4CADA&ved=0CAoQ_AUoAg&biw=1276&bih=670).

Comment: @OlinLathrop All he asked was `some tips on where to start`, not to make a design for him.

Answer (score 2):

> i'm looking for some tips on where to start

If you are totally new to electronics, I think it's a good idea to spend some time learning the basics rather than plunging in to a complicated project.

Google is a good way to find circuits - you need to compare lots of results to weed out the badly designed stuff (in which the intertubes abound).

I suggest you get yourself a basic set of tools (soldering iron, solder, multimeter) and try assembling a couple of kits - and work out how they work.

For your specific project, I would try to learn a bit about audio signal levels, basic amplifiers, simple audio mixers, dealing with noise and so on.

> and if it possible at all?

It is certainly possible, and probably not beyond most hobbyists.